# Error when accessing private members from a friend function in C++

Tags: c++

I'm having a problem when overloading the '<<' operator for a dynamically allocated Table class in c++.

Here is the header file:

```
#ifndef INT_TABLE_H
#define INT_TABLE_H

#include<cstdlib>
#include<iostream>

class Table {
public:
    Table();
    Table(int n);
    Table(const Table& orig);
    virtual ~Table();
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Table& t);

private:
    int** table;
    int rows;
    int cols;
};

#endif /* INT_TABLE_H */
```

And here is the function in question:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Table& t)
{
    for(int i=0;i<t.rows;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<t.cols; j++)
        {
            std::cout<<"["<<"."<<"]";
        }
        std::cout<<std::endl;
    }
}
```

When I run code, I get the following output:

```
  1 [main] algproject1 6360 cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to algproject1.exe.stackdump
this is a table
[.][.][.][.][.]
[.][.][.][.][.]
[.][.][.][.][.]
[.][.][.][.][.]
[.][.][.][.][.]

RUN FAILED (exit value 35,584, total time: 1s)
```

The table still prints, but I get the above error.
I have found that when I replace t.rows and t.cols with a number (5 for example), it runs correctly without an issue. Does anyone have insight as to what the problem is? Dynamic memory allocation is a relatively new concept to me.

Another quick question, how would I access the elements of the table for printing? When I replace "." with t[0][0], I get the following error:

```
int_table.cpp: In function 'std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Table&)':
int_table.cpp:50:34: error: no match for 'operator[]' (operand types are 'const Table' and 'int')
             std::cout<<"["<<t[0][0]<<"]";
                              ^
```

Any help or explanation you can provided is very much appreciated!

Comment: `class Table` doesn't have an `operator[]`. Did you mean `t.table[0][0]`?

Comment: Wow. Very silly of me. Thank you.
Any idea about the first part?

Comment: No, the problem is in the parts of the code you haven't shown.

Comment: Could you post code for a minimum, complete, verifiable example in which you are using this operator<<? http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: where is the return value of <<  operator? you didn't supply enough code eg: implementation of constructor, dtor... also you didn't overload subscript operator []

Answer (score 1):

for anyone wondering, I've found the issue.

In the operator<< function I failed to actually return the output stream with 
    return out;

A simple fix that I should have seen, but thanks for the input none-the-less!